# sails.js stopped to work after cloning from repository

Tags: npm, sails.js

After adding to git and cloning **sails.js** application back to another desktop my application stopped to work correctly. e.g. I am able to successfully run `sails lift` command, however when trying to load login page I see that the page is not loaded properly:

[image]

and I receive multiple errors in browser console (back end console is ok and does not drop any errors):

```
cloud.setup.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cloud is not defined
    at cloud.setup.js:13

Uncaught ReferenceError: parasails is not defined
    at ajax-button.component.js:12

ajax-form.component.js:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: parasails is not defined
    at ajax-form.component.js:20

Uncaught ReferenceError: parasails is not defined
    at js-timestamp.component.js:15
...
```

I checked node_modules folder and parasails is included there.

I didn't include node_module to my repo as I can always run `npm install` after cloning.

I managed to create and successfully run a new sails.js application on my desktop without any issues.

So, there must be an error with the files I pushed or didn't pushed to git.

Answer (score 3):

In .gitignore file I had **dependencies/** folder excluded.

That rule was excluding any file in **assets/dependencies** subfolder, where a number of sails.js files are located, e.g. parasails.js, etc.